# Expression of type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[Models.Option]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1[Models.Option]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-3.1

In the following Query, I want to Sort the Children List of a Parent based on Index Property, which I encounter with the following error ...
How to Fix it ?

```
Expression of type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[Models.Option]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1[Models.Option]'
```

Code :

```
[HttpGet("name={name}&includeSettings={includeSettings}&includeFields={includeFields}")]
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult<Models.Form>> GetFormByName(string name, bool includeSettings = false, bool includeFields = false)
{
    var varForm = _context.Forms
        .Where(current => current.Name.Contains(name))
        .AsQueryable();

    if (includeSettings == true)
    {
        varForm = varForm
            .Include(current => current.FormUiSetting)
            .Include(current => current.FormResultSetting);
    }

    if (includeFields == true)
    {
        varForm = varForm
            .Include(current => current.FieldItems)
                .ThenInclude(field => field.Validations)
            .Include(current => current.FieldItems)
                .ThenInclude(field => field.Options.OrderBy(option => option.Index));
    }

    return await varForm.SingleOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

My Model is Like This :
Some FieldItems have Options List and Some not have it...

```
public class Form
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    --- some props ---
    public List<FieldItem> FieldItems { get; set; }
}

public class FieldItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FieldItemName { get; set; }
    public List<Validation> Validations { get; set; }
}

public class OptionableFieldItem : FieldItem
{
    public List<Options> Options { get; set; }
}

public class Validation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    --- some props ---
}

public class Options
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Index { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change like below:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Form>> GetFormByName(string name, bool includeSettings = false, bool includeFields = false)
{
    var varForm = _context.Forms
        .Where(current => current.Name.Contains(name))
        .AsQueryable();

    if (includeSettings == true)
    {
        varForm = varForm
            .Include(current => current.FormUiSetting)
            .Include(current => current.FormResultSetting);
    }

    if (includeFields == true)
    {
        varForm = varForm
            .Include(current => current.FieldItems)
                .ThenInclude(field => field.Validations)
            .Include(current => current.FieldItems)
                .ThenInclude(field => field.Options);
        varForm.FirstOrDefaultAsync().Result.FieldItems.Options = varForm.FirstOrDefaultAsync()
                                                                            .Result.FieldItems.Options
                                                                            .OrderBy(o => o.Index).ToList();
    }

    return await varForm.SingleOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

My model:

```
public class Form
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public FormUiSetting FormUiSetting { get; set; }
    public FormResultSetting FormResultSetting { get; set; }
    public FieldItem FieldItems { get; set; }
}
public class FormUiSetting
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FormUiName { get; set; }

}
public class FormResultSetting
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FormResultName { get; set; }
}
public class FieldItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FieldItemName { get; set; }
    public Validation Validations { get; set; }
    public List<Options> Options { get; set; }
}
public class Validation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ValidateName { get; set; }
}
public class Options
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Index { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

For your requirement,it seems no need to use `FieldItem`,just use `OptionableFieldItem`.

Model:

```
public class Form
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
public List<OptionableFieldItem> OptionableFieldItems { get; set; }
}

public class FieldItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FieldItemName { get; set; }
    public List<Validation> Validations { get; set; }
}

public class OptionableFieldItem : FieldItem
{
    public List<Options> Options { get; set; }
}

public class Validation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ValidateName { get; set; }
}

public class Options
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Index { get; set; }
}
```

Actions:

```
if (includeFields == true)
{
    varForm = varForm.Include(current => current.OptionableFieldItems)
                    .ThenInclude(field => field.Validations)
                .Include(current => current.OptionableFieldItems)
                    .ThenInclude(field => field.Options);
    var data = varForm.FirstOrDefaultAsync().Result.OptionableFieldItems;
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        item.Options = item.Options.OrderBy(o => o.Index).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer

In my model (see edited question again), FieldItem Class is a Base Class, and the OptionableFieldItem Class inherits from it and includes the Options List. In fact, some FieldItem have Options List and some not have it... How can I Cast FieldItems List to OptionableFieldItem Class?

Comment: Hi,Did my answer help you?If so,could you accept as answer?